# Flash AS3 - Objects of same base class in library - Type coercion failed

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class

This happens to me a lot and I've yet to find a good solution. Say you have two classes, Tree (com.company.Tree) and Fruit (com.company.Fruit). On the stage in Flash, the Tree has an instance of Fruit (class=fruit1, base class=com.company.Fruit), and it's instance name is fruit. Everything is fine, until you duplicate the tree and fruit movie clips to create a 2nd tree, which has a DIFFERENT instance of Fruit (class=fruit2, base class=com.company.Fruit), but whose instance name in the 2nd tree is also fruit. This is necessary because the code for the Tree class references "fruit" (fruit.x += 20, for example).

I get this:

```
 Warning: All instances named 'fruit' will be automatically declared as fruit1 in symbols that use fruit as their base class. In symbols that are linked to user-defined base classes, instances with the same name must be of the same type.
```

And of course this:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert fruit2@4be85871 to fruit1.
```

Comment: There's something strange in your setup here: you have two instances of com.company.Tree - are they the same class or are they class=tree1 and class=tree2? Are your fruit instances defined inside the tree instances, or side-by-side on the stage?

If you could to explain your library and stage set ups more clearly, I may be able to help.

Comment: The trees have the same base class (Tree). The fruit instances are inside the trees, one fruit per tree. Hope that helps. This is still a big problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the compile option to "Automatically declare stage instances"? In this case, you may have to disable that and add:

```
public var fruit:Fruit;
```

to your Tree class. This would assign "fruit" to your MovieClip on the stage with an instance name of "fruit" and avoid the conflict. Check [this post](http://jasconius.com/2009/07/in-symbols-that-are-linked-to-user-defined-base-classes-instances-with-the-same-name-must-be-of-the-same-type/) out for more.

Answer (score 1):

typeoneerror's answer does work.  Flash will set the type of fruit2 to fruit1 which is essentially the same thing as actually setting it's Base to Fruit.

A pretty annoying warning but everything works fine

Comment: Since the link in typeoneerror's post is dead, I think I'll also direct the curious to a post on my own blog about this same topic.  http://www.scriptocalypse.com/?p=5

Answer (score 0):

http://jongrant.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/as3-warning-all-instances-named-will-be-automatically-declared-as-in-symbols-that-use-as-their-base-class-in-symbols-that-are-linked-to-user-defined-base-classes-instances-with-the-same-name/

This solution works perfect for me, just uncheck the box and everthing is ok.

File->Publish Settings->Flash->Settings… you have Automatically declare stage instances